# eliminate duplicate anagram in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, anagram

```
s = ['4', 'poke', 'aaagmnrs', 'pkoe', 'okpe', 'ekop', 'anagrams']

final_list = []

for i in range(0, len(s)):
    for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
        if sorted(s[i]) == sorted(s[j]):
            if s[i] not in final_list:
                final_list.append(s[i])

print(final_list)
```

I am getting this output

```
['poke', 'aaagmnrs', 'pkoe', 'okpe']
```

I need this output

```
['poke', 'aaagmnrs']
```

If there are multiple items in a list that are anagrams of earlier item in a list, I basically need only the first occurence. For example 'poke' occurs before 'pkoe', 'okpe' and 'ekop' i need only 'poke' in the output list. Same with 'aaagmnrs'. Since 'aaagmnrs' occurs before 'anagrams' i need only 'aaagmnrs' in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider keeping a list of the sorted version of found anagram, then checking if that list of sorted strings contains the sorted string. You can also break from the inner loop when you find a matching item in the list after you're done adding it to the lists if necessary:

```
s = ['4', 'poke', 'aaagmnrs', 'pkoe', 'okpe', 'ekop', 'anagrams']

final_list = []
final_list_sorted = []

for i in range(0, len(s)):
    sortedi = sorted(s[i])
    for j in range(i+1, len(s)):
        if sortedi == sorted(s[j]):
            if sortedi not in final_list_sorted:
                final_list.append(s[i])
                final_list_sorted.append(sortedi)

            break

print(final_list)
```

> ```
> ['poke', 'aaagmnrs']
> ```